# Integration test works for FromBody but not FromForm

Tags: c#, http, testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing integration tests for a C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using `WebApplicationFactory`.

I can test a `POST` method with `FromBody` like this:

```
var DTO = //populate Dto
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DTO);
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 var response1 = await _client.PostAsync("/api/Main/Function1", content);
```

This works and hits the below function with the DTO populated with correct fields:

```
[HttpPost("Function1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Function1([FromBody] DTO values)
{
    // ....
}
```

However when I try to change `FromBody` to `FromForm`, the DTO values are NULL

```
    var DTO = //populate Dto
    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DTO);
    var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-url-formencoded");
    
    var response1 = await _client.PostAsync("/api/Main/Function1", content);

    [HttpPost("Function1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Function1([FromForm] DTO values)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: ````application/x-www-url-formencoded```` content needs different presentation (name-value pairs instead of json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an api endpoint like:

```
app.MapPost("/myentity/post", ([FromForm] MyEntity myEntity) =>
{
    
    return Results.Ok();
})

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could try :

```
    // Arrange
    var client = _factory.CreateClient();
    var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "name")           
     });
    // Act
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

    // Assert
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```